# How should jcarousel be installed and configured?

Tags: 8

To achieve a slider with 5 slides in sight and sliding 1 at a time, I thought https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel would be a good choice. Also, because I already use views_slideshow.
However the installation instructions are a bit confusing. They seem to relate to Drupal 7 and/or combined with Drupal 8.

At first I installed through Composer and activated the module in Drupals' User Interface. This did not work.
Then I downloaded the zip and tried to place files in different locations. Because it is not clear to me where I should place files, this also failed.

Anybody knows how I could get this to work?

Update: as was noticed by Stefan, the dist folder should be in an other location than the docs (sites/all/libraries/jcarousel/dist) indicate. I moved the contents of the dist folder to that new location (/libraries/jcarousel/lib), this didn't make it work yet. I can see the carousel options in the view that I made, but it doesn't function yet.

I'm setting the view > slideshow settings > widgets > pager type to jcarousel pager. At that point there's a select list for skin without options to choose from. The output of the slider is an unformatted list with the slider below that.
Perhaps I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's support request to a third-party module, where this issue has been moved to: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel/issues/3084864

Comment: It's not just that issue, leymannx. Please hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the code you need to put the jcarousel library here:

```
/libraries/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js
```

This means install the module as usual and then put the library like given above in the folder libraries

But it seems that there is truly a flaw in setup instructions: The module page states like this:

> Download and extract the jCarousel library to libraries folder of
>   drupal root. The source code can be found here:
>
> https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/releases
>
> the folder name you create for this will need to be "jcarousel". the
>   full path should be: libraries/jcarousel
>
> and when you are done, the following path will need to be available:
>   sites/all/libraries/jcarousel/dist

This is a mixup of D7 and D8 as TO already stated and in addition if you do it like so, the path given in views_slideshow_jcarousel.libraries.yml will not be available.

I created an issue to maybe get this fixed: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_jcarousel/issues/3084864

Comment: Stefan, thanks for your confirmation of the file structure flaw and the issue you created. I moved the dist folder to the new location, this didn't make it work yet. See update in the question

Comment: If you use the current version of the module you need to put it to: /libraries/jcarousel/lib - only if you use my patch from the issue than /libraries/jcarousel/dist would be the path.

Comment: Do you mean I have to move the contents of the dist folder to /libraries/jcarousel/lib or to /libraries/jcarousel/lib/dist?

Comment: Yes, move the contents of the dist to lib folder or just rename dist folder to lib. But be aware that is actually not correct and the path might be changed to dist again later if the patch from the issue will be accepted. But with current version it needs to be placed in lib folder.

Comment: Perhaps I'm still doing something wrong, this doesn't change things. I edited the question a bit Stefan.

Comment: As Views Slideshow JCarousel also needs the Views Slideshow module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) and this module needs some libraries installed to the libraries path too. Have you done this? see readme https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_slideshow/blob/8.x-4.6/README.txt

Comment: Yes, the slideshow works fine, the only extra option I want to have is that it shows 5 slides at once and advances 1 at a time. That's why I thought of jcarousel.

Comment: Okay, I just tried the module myself and could not achive your desired output of 5 slides at once, while the module seems to basically work. The "skin" section also seems to be a remnant of D7 version and older library. Overall I think this module is really in alpha-Status (as the module version says) and I suppose there is missing function. Maybe you should try some other module. I can recommend slick (https://www.drupal.org/project/slick). Sorry, I am out here now. I thought there was only a specific problem here, but it seems this is way more generally with the module.

Comment: Okay, nice that you have tried it and get the same results. Now I know the failing setup was not just by accident.